# Edge bundling fit road network

Tags: python, gis, visualization

I am trying to use edge bundling to process the starting and ending points. How can I make the bundling results fit the road network?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.